# center a div popup on the screen from iframe

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe

Have a iframe in my page, I need show a small div popup using javascript codes in iframe. The domain of iframe and parent is NOT same. how to center this div popup in whole screen.
I found another similar question, but no answer in it.

Comment: Can you show some code examples?

Comment: You shouldn't do this, and I'm pretty sure all browsers out there are trying very hard to make sure you won't be able to do this. Cross-domain access allow for too many security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit that iframe, but you can make the div with a bigger z-index than of that iframe and that be aligned inside of the iframe.

#### Steps:

1. Create a div, with an class `test` (in my steps).
2. Change its left position to the iframe `offsetLeft` plus `offsetWidth/2` (of iframe), and subtract with the `offsetWidth/2` of the div, you do the same to the top (replacing `offsetWidth` per `offsetHeight` and `offsetLeft` to `offsetTop`).

It may be so:

```
div.style.left=(iframe.offsetLeft+(iframe.offsetWidth/2))-div.offsetWidth/2+'px',
div.style.top=(iframe.offsetTop+(iframe.offsetHeight/2))-div.offsetHeight/2+'px'
```

I recommend to update the `top` and `left` CSS properties of the div everytime that the user scroll the page also, else the div will not combine with screen.